How do I specify host as a variable in ansible?
There are examples on the internet but none of them seem to work for me:
test.yaml
---

- hosts: "{{ non_default_host }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'This is the host specified"

then I run this with
ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yaml -e "non_default_host=<somehost>"

All I see is bunch of warnings:
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided host list is empty, only localhost is available
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring somehost

PLAY [somehost]
skipping: no hosts matched

But if I change the hosts to all
test.yaml
---

- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: 'This is the host specified"

and then below command this works fine
   ansible-playbook -i 'somehost,'  test.yaml


Does it work when you run the one with hosts: all with ansible-playbook -i hosts  test.yaml?

Does <somehost> exist in the inventory? The argument to hosts: must be listed in your inventory (which is what your last command accomplishes).

For an inventory file example with content of
[example:children]
default
non_default

[default]
node[01:03].example.com

[non_default]
node[01:03].example.net

checked with
ansible-inventory --inventory example --graph
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
  |--@example:
  |  |--@default:
  |  |  |--node01.example.com
  |  |  |--node02.example.com
  |  |  |--node03.example.com
  |  |--@non_default:
  |  |  |--node01.example.net
  |  |  |--node02.example.net
  |  |  |--node03.example.net

a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "This is the 'hosts: {{ host }}' specified"

called via
 ansible-playbook --inventory example test.yml --extra-vars="host=node03.example.com"

will result into an output of
PLAY [node03.example.com] **********************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************
ok: [node03.example.com] =>
  msg: 'This is the ''hosts: node03.example.com'' specified'

Documentation

How to build your inventory
Patterns: targeting hosts and groups

